# How does one solve this optimization?

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

In a videogame, there are N levels, each one requires you to have a certain amount of energy in order to win that level. You start the game at level 0 with 0 energy, and every time you win a level, you spend the energy the level requires (your energy can't go below 0). Also each level has 0, 1, or more shops that sells energy amount E at cost C. If you find yourself without enough energy to pass a level, you lose because you can't go to previous levels to buy from other shops. Whenever you buy from a shop, your new amount of energy is E (the one the shop sells), that is, it doesn't sum up to your previous energy.

The question: What is the minimum money necessary in order to win all N levels? (assuming money is infinite and you can buy all shops you want,... but I want to optimize it so that it buys only the necessary)

I'm interested to know how does one finds the solution for this. Are any problem solving technique that solves this kind of problems, if so, can you explain?. Are there similar known problems that I should study first?

I tried using recursive backtracking, with the hope of finding overlapping states and use dynamic programming, but I didn't find them. My states where: for all shops, fork two branches... buys the shop, or doesn't.

Comment: This seems similar in structure to the 8 queens problem and that is solved using backtracking depth first search but it seems like you have already tried it. I would not branch on every shop (buy or not buy)  because buying from multiple shops on the same level does not give me any benefit since energy does not sum. I think a good idea would be to buy the minimum energy which allows you to jump to the next level, if at any point you are stuck at a level, backtrack and buy a higher energy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly easy problem because energy doesn't sum. That means that your energy E(N) after buying in level N does not depend on what you did in levels 0...N-1. That also means you can work backwards; what are the last shops you could have bought energy to reach the end? And for each of those candidates, what are the shops before them where you must have bought energy to reach that last shop?